# How to install sage on ubuntu 18.04 LTS from downloaded tar.bz2 file?

Tags: sagemath

i have downloaded sage from official website. i have a tar.bz2 file in my \home\pritesh\download folder in Ubuntu. Now, how to install sage in my system.
please give a step by step procedure.
i am a new user of ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

From the official website, there are several methods to install sagemath.
The easiest one is to run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential m4 dpkg-dev 
sudo apt-get install sagemath
```

For more details about the different installation methods, please visit the [installation guide](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/installation/)

Answer (score 1):

If you have downloaded the file sage-8.8-Ubuntu_18.04-x86_64.tar.bz2, extract the folder sage-8.8-Ubuntu_18.04-x86_64. It contains a single folder SageMath.  Move SageMath to any location of your choice (I put it in the folder ~/Sage).  Open SageMath and run the executable file `./sage`. That should set up Sage.  You can then open the terminal version by running`~/Sage/SageMath/sage` and the notebook version with one of the following `~/Sage/SageMath/sage --notebook=jupyter` (the new notebook interface),  `~/Sage/SageMath/sage --notebook=sagenb` (the old notebook interface), or `~/Sage/SageMath/sage --notebook=` (a prompt to choose which interface you want). I like to put these in bash scripts in my `~/.local/bin`. After installation the HTML version of the documents can be easily accessed by opening `~/Sage/SageMath/local/share/doc/sage/html/en/index.html` in a web browser.